# SQL syntax error near "WHERE" 2

Tags: sql, syntax-error, where-clause

Query:

```
select distinct R1.name, R2.name
from (
    (
    select Ra.mID mID, Re.rID rID, Re.name name
    from Rating Ra join Reviewer Re using (rID)
    ) R1
    ,
    (
    select Ra.mID mID, Re.rID rID, Re.name name
    from Rating Ra join Reviewer Re using (rID)
    ) R2
where R1.mID = R2.mID and R1.rID > R2.rID;
```

Result:

```
Query failed to execute: near "where": syntax error
```

I am guessing the problem has something to do with the pointer variables in the FROM clause that are referred to in the WHERE clause, but I can't figure it out. I haven't been very wary of my WHEREs recently...

Comment: remove the bracket on the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch in the number of opening and closing brackets in the provided SQL.

There may also be other issues, but that's less clear without knowing what db server / version you are running.

Comment: Ah I feel so dumb. Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Check your php version as your query is perfect. It may possible because some php version is not supporting sub query.

Comment: Pho would only relay the query to a database server, there's no mention in his post of what, if any, client code he's using... And the SQL has a big, obvious error!